# Is there a simple way to see a list of global variables in GDB?

Tags: gdb

I have an application that needs to use GDB/MI to get information about a process. Right now I am setting a breakpoint in main and running the process. By using "info locals" I can get a neat list of the local variables in the current frame. While this is good, I need to be able to see what the global variables are.

Is there a way to do this that isn't too painful? I can use "info variables" and get a list of ALL variables that is way too extensive and could hurt the performance of my application. Is there a simpler way to get a list of the global variables?

EDIT: Added that I'm wanting to use GDB/MI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found a solution for what I want to do.

I followed this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14663961/how-to-count-all-global-variables-in-the-cpp-file). However, I found that when I ran the command that was given in the answer, I got some unneeded garbage (I'm running this on a Mac). I fixed this by eliminating the lines that end in .eh and I noticed that the other lines had lines that started with "__" so I eliminated lines with " __" (that's a space before the two underscores). I used the following to get the correct output:

```
g++ -O0 -c test.cpp && nm test.o | egrep ' [A-Z] ' | egrep -v ' [UTW] ' | egrep -v '.eh' | egrep -v ' __'
```

Answer (score 2):

According to GDB [docs](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Symbols.html#index-info-variables-918) the `info variables` will print out any variables defined outside of functions. This will include your globals and static variables.

If you know the name of the global, or follow a particular naming pattern, you can provide GDB with regex to narrow it down.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's my problem. I don't know the names of the global variables, and I need some way to find out what they are. I can get the output from that long list of static and global variables and try to parse out where they start (by looking for File: xxxx), but unfortunately performance is an issue.

Comment: I failed to mention that I'm using GDB/MI, and it looks like there is no equivalent to this command anyways.

Comment: You can run all "console" commands through MI mode, just use -interpreter-exec console "command" as explained here: https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/GDB_002fMI-Miscellaneous-Commands.html#%2dinterpreter%2dexec